# Selecting multitple, specific lines in Sublime Text using the keyboard

Tags: selection, text-editor, sublimetext

Let's say that I have a file with 1000 lines and I would like to place 3 cursors on, say, lines 1, 456 and 849. there are no common words in these three lines that I could select with CMD-D.

I know this is possible using the mouse (CMD+left click), but can I do it using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways, but at least here is one that I would use.

There is a plugin called [PowerCursor](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PowerCursors), that allows adding cursors with keyboard just like the mouse click.  I would use that between the normal jump to line with keyboard.